# django-less issue - can't collecstatic

Tags: python, django, less

I'm using

https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-less

because I want to use less for my project. I've added 'less.finders.LessFinder' to my STATICFILES_FINDERS in django settings but I get this error when I try to run ./manage.py collectstatic

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 103, in collect
    for finder in finders.get_finders():
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 252, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 27, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/jean-lucmartin/lolsales/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 265, in _get_finder
    (module, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module less.finders: "No module named finders"
```

So it's obvious that there's no 'finders' module.. BUT WHY!?!?!?

Comment: Did you add `less` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and do you have the `less` django app in your directory?

Comment: I have less in INSTALLED_APPS. What do you mean by "do you have the less django app in your directory"?

Comment: So my friend helped me fix this. For some reason there's a problem with the pip package 'django-less'. I was advised to try pip install https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-less/zipball/master and that worked perfectly!